# Django profile form not hitting the database

Tags: python, json, django, django-forms

I am running a Django Application.

views.py:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_anonymous)
def signup(request):
 if request.method=='POST':
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user=user
        response = {'status':'success','message':'Registered Successfully'}
        return JsonResponse(response,safe=False)

    elif user_form.errors:
        ress = {'status':'Failed','message':'Username already Exists'}
        return JsonResponse(ress,safe=False)
    elif profile_form.errors:
        resss = {'status':'Failed','message':'mobile number already Exists'}
        return JsonResponse(resss,safe=False)
```

forms.py :

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta():
       model=User
       fields=('username','password')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model=Profile
       widgets = {
        'address_line_1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Door No,Building'}),
        'address_line_2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Area,Locality'}),
    }
       fields=('first_name','last_name','mobile_no','email','address_line_1','address_line_2','postal_code','city','country')
```

user_form is hitting the database, but profile_form is not hitting the database.If i register with the same mobile_no 2 times, it is showing "Registered successfully" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling **`save(...)`** method

```
# Your code
...
user.set_password(user.password)
user.save()
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
profile.save() # saving profile
... 
# your code
```

Comment: Thanks got it fixed. Firstly i called save() before profile.user, so i got error.

Comment: Consider to Accept the answer. :)